# Как правильнее написать данное предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В каком падеже стоит использовать слово бабушка в этом предложении: я буду хорошей бабушкой. Или же я буду хорошая бабушка?

Может есть какое правило, по которому установлено правильное написание?

Спасибо заранее за ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Нормативный вариант:  (1)  *Я буду **хорошей бабушкой***.

Вариант с И.п. лучше записать с инверсией: (2) ***А бабушка я буду хорошая.***

Это связано с тем, что для прилагательных выбор падежа более свободный, чем для существительных.

Эта тема рассмотрена у Розенталя.

Розенталь §179. Формы сказуемого (п.3)

3. Существительное и прилагательное в функции именной части составного сказуемого могут стоять **как в форме именительного, так и в форме творительного падежа;** ср.: И в семье его Савельич был свой человек (Мельников:Печерский). – И у Ивашиных он был своим человеком (Чехов); День был тусклый, теплый (Шукшин):

   Какие **факторы** влияют на выбор?

1) Обычно в этих случаях именительный падеж существительного указывает на **устойчивый** признак предмета, на постоянно присущую ему качественную характеристику, а творительный падеж – на **временный** признак

2) Творительный падеж свойствен **книжной** речи, а именительный – **разговорной**.

http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/62.htm

Comment: Второй вариант вообще не звучит. Так не говорят. У Розентяля другое (прошедшее время). Ещё пример: *Я буду очень хороший мальчик.*

Comment: С прилагательными в И.п. связка "буду" используется: ...Васька вспомнил, как уверенно говорил отец о том, что жизнь будет хорошая. [А. П. Гайдар. Дальние страны (1931)] Возможно, при инверсии лучше звучит: А бабушка я буду хорошая.

Comment: При инверсии нормально, но не без.

Comment: Сейчас поправлю ответ.

Comment: Хотя замечу, что с людьми оно хуже звучит (чем "*жизнь будет хорошая*") - не уверен, что это правильно.

Comment: Нормально звучит.

Comment: –@oleedd, как можно оценивать ответ, исходя из собственных убеждений? Звучности или беззвучности. Здесь приветствуется аргументированная критика.